# google appengine receive email error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I'm in trouble. I'm playing now for a long time with receiving email in google apps but in my application Logs only get this:

```
0.1.0.20 - - [13/Jun/2013:08:42:23 -0700] "POST /_ah/mail/contact@myappid.appspotmail.com HTTP/1.1" 200 0 - - "myappid.appspot.com" ms=69 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.100008 app_engine_release=1.8.1 instance=00c61b117c2fb913155f167711d12979c818fd
```

My mail handler script schould be this: mailmain.py

```
import logging
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler
from google.appengine.api import mail 

class LogSenderHandler(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, mail_message):
        tobesent = mail_message.subject
        logging.info("From: " + mail_message.sender)
        logging.info("To:" + mail_message.to)
        logging.info("Subject: " + mail_message.subject)
        logging.info("Date: " + mail_message.date)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([LogSenderHandler.mapping()], debug=True)
```

and my app.yaml is this:

```
application: myappid
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: no

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /_ah/mail/contact@myappid.appsportmail.com
  script: mailmain.py 
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: mailmain.py

inbound_services:
- mail
```

I've tried playing with the script so I have many versions, some ending in this (if this matters) but really nothing works:

```
def main():
    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([LogSenderHandler.mapping()], debug=True)
    run_wsgi_app(application)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I do have a favicon.ico uploaded as well.

Googled the error up for hours and hours and nothing works. 
Here on Stackoverflow I've found for similar error message solutions such as correct `recieve` into `receive` but this is not the case here. I've copied other solutions as well, also this from [GITHUB](https://github.com/darragh/appengine-email-gateway-example) so I believe this question is not a duplicate.

Comment: myappid.appspotmail.com don't need to be register

Comment: @Stevko I would love it to be that easy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mixing up CGI and WSGI. See Python27 getting started.
Docs : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingwebapp

Yaml update :

```
application: myappid
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /_ah/mail/contact@myappid.appsportmail.com
  script: mailmain.app
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: mailmain.app

inbound_services:
- mail
```

With WSGI you do not need the run_wsgi_app stuff.

And some background about CGI / WSGI: http://blog.notdot.net/2011/10/Migrating-to-Python-2-7-part-1-Threadsafe

Comment: Thank you. This was the problem. Now it works. Though if I run myappid.appengine.com it would give ``404 Not Found The resource could not be found.`` in the browser, but when I send the email it works **PERFECTLY**. I've checked out the links as well and now I know this appengine thingy a little better. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yoy have to add a main webapp2 handler like the helloworld in the get started, which maps to url: /.*